# How can I check whether a variable is an instance of 'npt.ArrayLike'?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, type-hinting

I declared a function that should only accept array-like values, as follows:

```
def func(data: Optional[npt.ArrayLike] = None) -> None:

    if not isinstance(data, npt.ArrayLike):
        ValueError(f"Keyword argument 'data' should be <class 'npt.ArrayLike'>: got {type(data)}")
    
    # do some stuff

    return None
```

However, when passing the function *any* values, the following exception is raised:

```
TypeError: Subscripted generics cannot be used with class and instance checks
```

My aim is to be able to check that what is passed to the function is the right type of value, exactly as I would do with `bool`, `str`, and `pd.DatFrame`, for example.

Comment: what is `npt` ?

Comment: @Copperfield It's the alias for `numpy.typing`, a convention from the official Numpy documentation -> [link](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/typing.html)

Comment: look like *ArrayLike* is only for static type checkers and can't be use with `isinstance`, so you would need to check vs the specifics clasess you want or a subset there off. For the numpy case you can use `numpy.ndarray`

Comment: a quick look at the [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/main/numpy/typing) code, reveal that they use a bunch of protocols among other thing and those by itself can't be used for isinstance without the [runtime_checkable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.runtime_checkable) decorator, which the source doesn't have... You can try asking the numpy developers to make that work with `isinstance`

Comment: @Copperfield it looks like my choice is then either to manually check for every type supported by *ArrayLike* (which kind of seems to defeat the purpose of `npt.ArrayLike` in the first place), or to contact Numpy's develpers and ask for a feature. I'll look into that, thank you